# Sum to infinity using exponential series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate $S=\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3\times 1!} +\frac{1}{4\times 2!} -\frac{1}{5\times 3!} +\ldots$ up to infinity.

I am not able to plug in the exponential series. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}S&=&\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3!}+\frac{3}{4!}-\frac{4}{5!}+\ldots\\&=&1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{1}{5!}+\ldots\\&=&2\left(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+\ldots\right)-1\\&=&2(1-e^{-1})-1\\&=&1-\frac{2}{e}\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Strong hint:**$$S = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{1}{(n+2)n!}= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{n+1}{(n+2)!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}\right)$$

Comment: It is not really telescopic, as the sign changes the terms *add up* rather than cancel - but they add up to a series that should be well-known to the OP.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Recall, $e^{-x}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^n}{n!}$

Hence, $xe^{-x}=x-x^2+\frac{x^3}{2!}-\frac{x^4}{3!}+\dots$

Now define, $f(x)=\int_{0}^xte^{-t}dt$

For $x=1$, we are working within the radius of convergence of the above power series and hence term by term integration is allowed! Note that $f(1)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3 \times 1!}+\frac{1}{4 \times 2!}-\frac{1}{5 \times 3!}+\dots$ and also from above, $$f(x)=-xe^{-x}-e^{-x}+1$$ Thus, $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3 \times 1!}+\frac{1}{4 \times 2!}-\frac{1}{5 \times 3!}+\dots= f(1)=1 - \frac{2}{e}$